# J2EE connect remote Oracle DB table

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am using Windows 7, 64 bit and using Eclipse for J2EE. I want to display the values from Oracle database through J2EE code. I tried with oracle tutorial. But I am getting the below error in Eclipse console. Please suggest me.

additional details: 
1. In remote oracle settings, I could see the Service-Name enabled, but not SID enabled.
2. My service name is 'sample.lan' and ofcourse I am working inside lan. whether I need to make any changes If I am connecting remote oracleDB table through LAN?

Connection string:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:1521:service-name", "username", "password");
```

Error:

```
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O-Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:673)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:711)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:385)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:558)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jsp.testDBconnection_jsp._jspService(testDBconnection_jsp.java:94)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:445)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:464)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:594)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:229)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1360)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:486)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:162)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:411)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: You couldn't even start the database connection. Post how you're trying to connect. Also, check that your server allows the connection through TCP/IP and you're sending the right parameters/credentials.

Comment: If you are really using a **service name** (rather than the **SID**) then the URL should be: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:1521/service-name` (note the `/` instead of the `:`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: After I added // instead of :, I get error, 'Invalid number format for port number'

Comment: My service name is 'sample.lan' and ofcourse I am working inside lan, whether is that any problem from Lan to connect remote oracle DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that you can reach port 1521 of your database host from wherever you are executing your java code.
2. Make sure too that you can connect to your database with some standard database client (SQL*plus for example) in order to check if your database is configured right
3. Check your connection URL to make sure if it is right (docs on that here http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC)

Besides that, just a remark: if your idea is to educate yourself or learn JDBC, this is perfectly right; if your code is intended for production, I strongly advise you against mixing database access into your presentantion layer (JSP).  I suggest you consider in that case to split your application in layers defined by its responsability.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture